# Problems with quotes in html

Tags: javascript, html

When I use a single quote in words like *you're* or *you'll* in the body tag, the browser interprets the code as a euro sign or % symbol. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: try add a backslash. like this: \'

Comment: Probably "Fix your character encodings"

Comment: can you be more descriptive and post the code to get exact solution?

Comment: Rewiew yor character encoding first.

Answer (score 3):

Encode your document correctly.

For example, in Notepad++, you might see this at the bottom:

[image: encoding]

That encoding needs to match whatever `Content-Type` header is being sent with your file. By the look of things, your source is encoded in UTF-8, but your `Content-Type` header is `iso-8859-1` or similar. Change it one way or the other (encode source in `iso-8859-1`, or set `Content-Type` header character set to `utf8`) but this is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the HTML Entity for an apostrophe:

`you&apos;re` and `you&apos;ll`

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5z49/1/)

Comment: Right single quote, for an `&apos;`trophe? Really?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Well, `&apos;` doesn't actually represent an apostrophe.

Comment: @BoltClock It... doesn't? What does it represent then?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Oh I meant to say, not in HTML. In XML/XHTML, `&apos;` does represent a straight single quote-aka-apostrophe, but HTML doesn't have that named entity reference for some reason (it only has `&#39;`). I'm not sure what the case is in HTML5. And even then, those who are *extremely* picky will say that a straight apostrophe isn't *really* an apostrophe either, although I suppose that's not really relevant...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&apos;` in the place where you would have put the `'`. This is what is called an [HTML Entity](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_symbols.asp).

Other important ones are:

- `&quot;` for `"`
- `&gt;` for `>`
- `&lt;` for `<`

Answer (score 0):

you can this `&CloseCurlyQuote;`
then you code will look like this

```
<p>you&CloseCurlyQuote;ll</p>
<p>you&CloseCurlyQuote;ll</p>
```

and check your character encodings too. Try changing to `utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

' is a special character. Instead use this `&#39;`

your's -->`<p>your&#39;s<p>`

Here is the list of all such character in  HTML
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to your `<head></head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Or just the shortcode:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The shortcode is the best practice because it's easy to remember and it works in every browser too.